# Question About Riemann Manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let be  $(M, g)$ and $(N, h)$ Riemann Manifolds. Suppose that $f \colon
 M \longrightarrow N$ is a smooth function such that $f^{*}h = g$. Prove that  $f$ is a immersion.

I attempt to use the Riemannian metric and manifold properties such as locally finite compactness, but I have many doubts; there may be some trick to solve this question??

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3409110/prove-that-the-pullback-f-g-of-a-riemannian-metric-g-is-a-riemannian-metri)

Comment: Hi, welcome. Yes, you should use the metric. No, I don’t think locally finite compactness has anything to do with it. Can’t you just test the definition of immersion?

Comment: The point is  $h_{f(m)}\big(df_m(v),df_m(v)\big)=(f^*h)_m(v,v)=g_m(v,v)>0$ for any $v\neq 0$ as $g_m$ is a metric. So, for any $v\neq 0$ we have $h_{f(m)}\big(df_m(v),df_m(v)\big)>0$; now $h_{f(m)}$ is a metric implies $df_m(v)\neq 0\implies df_m$ is injective for any $m\in M$.